# Beginning PLC programming

Tags: plc

I'm getting interested in PLC programming and my idea is to just try it. Therefore I need to simulate some real system, because it's to soon to look for some hardware. This is how I wish to do it (example):

1. Simulate some real system, ie. water tank with bleed and inlet valves, some water level sensor of course. These are controled and checked by PLC.
2. PLC simulator to control valves and get values from sensor. Also send data to some HMI/SCADA (PLCsim ?)
3. Some software to program the logic into PLC. (Step7 ?)
4. Some GUI for end user to check values and control valves manually (InTouch ?, ControlWeb ?, WinCC ?, LabView ?)

I don't know if this is possible completely by using software and if there is a chance it will work. Your advices and ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think it is a little unfair to close this as not a real question. This is a very big concern when you are trying to learn PLC programming. It's not like C, where can you just download gcc and get started. There are lots components to write and test a PLC program, and not many places to learn where to start.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely.  If money is an issue, AutomationDirect.com has a new product called Do-more where the programming software is free (called Designer) and it comes with a free PLC simulator.

I would then recommend writing separate code-block(s) to simulate "the process", where the code-block(s) READ from Outputs (discrete and analog) and WRITE to Inputs (discrete and analog) based on the Output states (and time, and random external events - think butterfly effect).

Disclosure: I work for Host Engineering, developers of Do-more.

If money is NOT an issue, I know there are lots of PLC Simulators and Process Simulator software out there that somebody can probably recommend.